# C# print GS1 barcode on network printer

Tags: c#, oracle, barcode

i have created an application which uses a Zebra printer to print a GS1 barcode. Actually it has an Oracle backend which generates a string and c# just passes the data to the printer.

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient zClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
zClient.Connect(zIP, zPort);
System.IO.StreamWriter zWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(zClient.GetStream());
zWriter.Write(zgs1);
zWriter.Flush();
zWriter.Close();
zClient.Close();
```

Now i need to test the GS1 barcode printing on a "normal" network printer with A4 paper.
Can somebody tell me how i can achieve that? In principle i would prefer to generate a string from Oracle and pass it on somehow to the printer through the c# application.

Thank you

EDIT: Thanks for the comments. I do not know how to print/transfer as GS1 code a string received from Oracle, for instance (without quotation marks) "(00)360222014120423545(15)141204(10)4805-397-TR". Form the comments i understand the only way is to render it first as PDF or image and then send it to the printer?If yes, how can i do that? I searched around but didn't really find free solutions. The printer (IP) is fixed.

Comment: Render it onto a PDF and print that?

Comment: There's over [1,700 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+printing) about printing in C#. Is there a specific problem you need help with? You can use a `PrintDialong` in WinForms to let users chose a printer, etc. Do you need to find a way to render the barcode as an image so you can print it? Please edit your question to clarify what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by using PrintDocument and the Spire.BarCode for .NET dll.